# How many smoke detectors does the A340 cargo deck have, and how are they wired?

Tags: electrical-system, airbus-a340, firefighting

I am a student of Aerospace Engineering, currently I am one year away from completing my degree. For my Electric Routing class I was asked to recreate in Catia the fire system in the cargo bay of an airplane and obviously justify why I made the decisions, for now I only have to decide which model I'm going to work with, its specifications, etc.

Looking for information on the internet, I decided that I will work with the Airbus A340 Lower Deck Cargo Compartment Class C. Doing a little research I understood that when there is a fire in this bay, from the cockpit the area is sealed and a percentage of Halon is released 1301.

But 2 questions arose that I would like to know:

1. How many and what type of fire sensors does this family of aircraft use (the type or model would be of great help)?
2. Does anyone know how this system is "wired" in general? I mean, in series, in parallel, which is better? How does the smoke sensor connect to Halon pumps?

This is information that I do not known where to find and I do not know if it is classified by the company and I need it to do my Catia model using the electronic Harness Discipline. For now I will be dedicated to modeling the part of my fuselage with the low cargo bay.

P.S: If you know of any regulations that I could read to better understand this topic, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: If you are doing this as a class project you are supposed to have learnt it from the said class right? It's explicitly asks "why you made the decisions" not airbus....

Comment: Hi and welcome on avaition.SE. This is not a forum, this is a Q&A website. Take a [tour](/tour) for more information. If your question is "how is smoke detector wired on A340 lower deck class C?", the title should reflect it (don't hesitate to edit your question to improve it). See the [help center](/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: @user3528438 Maybe the question was edited after your comment, but I think it's fair to ask now. I don't know where this information could be found either!

Comment: @user3528438 I agree with your assessment 100%. Sounds to me like the instructor is asking for the students' thoughts on the subject, not for them to research the how & why the manufacturer did it, then duplicate. I don't think this is a question that we can answer, as we'd essentially be doing homework for the OP. The "where do I look" portion is a reasonable question, but that's still OT at SE sites.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a homework assignment where the instructor seems to want the student's interpretation, not a regurgitation of what a manufacturer has done.

Comment: @FreeMan I'm one of the most-anti-homework people here, but I [believe](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3998/homework-questions-has-something-changed-perhaps-network-wide?cb=1) that open-ended and interesting questions should be judged on their own merits. There is a difference between seeking genuine knowledge that will help you do your assignment, and merely looking to tick a box. This is not ticking a box. Without the mention of homework, this would've made for a suitable question. Note, also, that the assignment is to route the electrics; the answer won't complete it.

Comment: In that case, @ZOMVID-20, it should be edited to remove all references to homework.

Comment: @FreeMan It could be better that way, yes, but we don't outright ban homework. Note that the homework is to do actual engineering drawings in 3D. They OP is not looking for ready models, they're asking for broader knowledge of how many detectors to wire up. This falls far short of doing someone's homework for them. If I were their instructor and saw this question, I'd find no reason to hold it against them, no deficiency in their performance, it's normal knowledge search in preparation for an assignment.

Comment: While I normally VtC almost immediately any "do my homework for me" type questions, I find I am leaning more in agreeing with ZOMVID-20's reasoning here, this coupled with Aircraft Design and Manufacturing being listed as explicitly on-topic, and I will VtLO.